# Serialization of chess game logic not succesful after clicking on "save game" button in Java GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, serialization

I am writing quite simple chess game with separate gui and logic.The "save game" button starts save FileDialog and from there the user chosen directory and file name is passed to savegame method in game logic class. There I create the file by FileOutputStream and then try to write into this file with ObjectOutputStream. However the IOException is raised and I dont know why.

Here is a snippet of how the Game class looks, which is the logic part of the chess game program.

```
public class Game implements Runnable, Serializable {

private final Board board;
private final transient MoveEvaluate moveEvaluator;

private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("game");

private  transient BoardGui gameGui;

private boolean whiteOnMove;
private boolean gameOver = false;
private boolean customBoardSetup = true;
private boolean setupIsDone = false;

public Game() {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "game created");
    this.board = new Board();
    this.whiteOnMove = true;
    this.moveEvaluator = new MoveEvaluate(this);
}
```

This is the save game method whis is inside the Game class. This method is called from gui action click listener.

```
 public void saveGame(String directoryName, String fileName) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(directoryName+fileName+".ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(this);
        out.close();
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "exception while serializing : IOException");
    }
}
```

I have in this method  `out.writeObject(this);` of which I think could be the problem. The Game class implements Runnable.

The question is where could be the problem . And how do you handle serialization of logic like this when gui and logic threads are running. 
Thank you

Here is the stack trace from this IOException

```
    SEVERE: File crated: C:\Users\Dagmar Kole4k85ov8\Desktop\l.ser
Kv? 29, 2016 10:32:30 DOP. com.mycompany.chess.Game saveGame
SEVERE: fileOut: C:\Users\Dagmar Kole4k85ov8\Desktop\l.ser
Kv? 29, 2016 10:32:30 DOP. com.mycompany.chess.Game saveGame
SEVERE: ObjectOutputStream made
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.mycompany.chess.Game.saveGame(Game.java:170)
    at com.mycompany.chess.GameGui.saveGame(GameGui.java:54)
    at com.mycompany.chess.BoardMenuGui.actionPerformed(BoardMenuGui.java:46)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Kv? 29, 2016 10:32:30 DOP. com.mycompany.chess.Game saveGame
SEVERE: exception while serializing : IOException
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace from the objection.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the mistake myself. The problem was that Logger wasn't set as `transient` at all classes being serialized. After adding transient to all, game succesfully saved.